# what technology used in mobile chat apps to receive messages?

Tags: android, ios, chat, messaging

I'm some kind of backend developer and don't know how mobile applications work. But I need to provide architecture for mobile chat application server.

I know that android apps using google services to receive push notifications from firebase, so we don't need run own application in endless loop and poll for new data at server.

That is prefect for push notifications, but firebase notification body limited by 4KB and don't fit for big messages.

So I can see only one realization:

1. Google services polling for FCM (ex-GCM) notifications
2. Receive some signal-like notification
3. According this notification my app go to server and download new message
4. Update local chat data
5. Show generated locally notification for new message

This way is looking pretty complicated, so I don't believe that this is only possible (and correct) way.

Another way is to keep websocket session opened every time or poll server manually. But these two operations should drain battery to much.

So how modern chat apps stay in sync even if they closed and device screen off?

Comment: You should check the background limitations on each platform. Android has [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) and [iOS has their own background restrictions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing_background_strategies_for_your_app)

Comment: you are hardcore. in short, we might use XMPP / socket / WebRTC / database syncing + remote notification. (notification is not reliable, it is a notice to user only)

Comment: @Horst `socket` and `WebRTC` must keep session opened, that should drain battery. `database syncing + remote notification` → Do you mean this way? http://developer.intersoftsolutions.com/display/crosslight/Using+Push+Notifications+for+Data+Sync That is pretty close to 5-step realization in my question.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you for information. I didn't know about android limitations, but even if OS limits application activity it is not explain how to sync chat app data affective.

Comment: what data do you want to sync and why? Not your code listens for the notification and keeps the socket / connection open but the OS does that for you. And what makes you say that that drains the battery too much?

Comment: @luk2302 `what data do you want to sync and why?` → I still don't understand usage cases clearly, but I guess it will be closer to mail system than chat. I should receive in realtime mail-like messages from support and be able to answer, but interval between messages may be hours or even days. Main reason to stay in sync is instantly receiving. `OS does that for you` → Ok, even if OS but not my app open socket session, anyway it need to open +1 new session to be able listen my server

Comment: You can use Firebase Realtime Database for this

Comment: @rzlvmp what i mean is (XMPP / socket / WebRTC / database syncing) + remote notification. we won't use the link way to update the messages as users can block the notification function.

Comment: I've just found this article https://www.cometchat.com/blog/popular-chat-and-instant-messaging-protocols

Comment: @Horst oh, yes. If user turns off notifications (even if it is hidden) that will break all logic and client stop to receive not just push notifications but all messages too. Good point. I lost sight of it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to make modern chat app then do some research on **XMPP**
These can be some best practices you can follow

1. setup XMPP server on backend with offline storage support
2. use client XMPP SDKS for apps to connect XMPP server.
3. use push notification in case of server connection lost to wake app
   and reconnect to XMPP
4. try to save large files on different server and send only url with
   body  if you want to keep your files urls private then use any
   client SDK that support implementation of uploading and downloading
   private file like AWSS3